# NLP - log analysis Scenario

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, nltk

I am trying to solve a problem related to log file analysis related to multi class classification.

In each log file. we  have multiple lines.
we can recieve error at any line.based on the error we need to assign the error to a particular team like Data issues to Data Quality team, DBA team for database issues, application team for java realated ..  so 2 challanges.

1st one:
how to identify if there is a error in a line in log file ?do we need to hardcode a pattern for it or can we use ML?

2nd one:
if we identify the line. now we need to assign it to a team. this is a multi class classification.

can you  help me..how to approach these. if you give me clue. i will search and leaen from them...thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a simple multi-class classification scenario. Each line belongs to one of many mutually exclusive classes: {no_error, error_type_1, error_type_2, ... error_type_N}. Any architecture oriented towards sentence classification would work.

Comment: Thank you. I have set of few sentences or statements which are errors. Can you please let me know if instead of using regexp to figure out the patterns in the line of the logfile using the above set.is there a way if we can identify that line or a file contains an error using ML.. ?

Comment: Each error log file is one class, create dataset of different error log file which correspond to different classes. Build the multi class classification model to identify the new error line. Take a look at example on [multi class classification](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-lstm-using-tensorflow-2-0-d88627c10a35).